# (AHK) Can't seem to get a pixel color statement working

Tags: autohotkey

I've only started yesterday. Im trying to make a script which performs a series of actions after a pixel color has been detected. When i run it it either ignores the if statement, or exits. And, i want it to look for the pixel color until it finds it.

```
PixelGetColor, color, 835, 620, Fast
if color = 0xCA3847
{
Random, rand, 15000, 25000
Sleep, %rand%
Click, Down, 1091 493
Click, Up, 1135 493
sleep, 300
^+c::
    {
     ClipSaved= %clipboard%
     send ^c
     ClipNew= %ClipSaved% %clipboard%
     clipboard = %ClipNew%
    }
sleep, 300
Click, 767, 558
sleep, 300
Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
    ClipBoard = %ClipBoard%
    Send ^v
    Sleep 1000
Click, 767, 558
sleep, 300
Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
    ClipBoard = %Clip0%
    VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)
sleep, 300
Click, 851, 619
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of solutions. You could use a loop (but the script will have problems responding to anything while in that loop) or use setTimer to repeatedly check for pixel color, and then do the actions that you want. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish workflow wise, but here is what I think might serve your purposes based on what I see. notice the use of "return" at the end of each sequence of actions.

```
#Persistent
setTimer, CheckforCA3847, 50

Return ; end auto-execute section at top of script.

CheckforCA3847:
PixelGetColor, color, 835, 620, Fast
if (color = 0xCA3847) {
    setTimer, %A_ThisLabel%, Off
    Random, rand, 15000, 25000
    Sleep, %rand%
    Click, Down, 1091 493
    Click, Up, 1135 493
    sleep, 300
    setTimer, %A_ThisLabel%, On
}
Return

^+c::
ClipSaved = %clipboard%
send ^c
ClipWait, .25 ; 250 milliseconds
ClipNew = %ClipSaved% %clipboard%
clipboard = %ClipNew%
sleep, 300
Click, 767, 558
sleep, 300
Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
ClipBoard = %ClipBoard%
Send ^v
Sleep 1000
Click, 767, 558
sleep, 300
Clip0 = %ClipBoardAll%
ClipBoard = %Clip0%
VarSetCapacity(Clip0, 0)
sleep, 300
Click, 851, 619
Return
```

Unless you are trying to have each sequence of events "fall into" the next sequence of events those returns will be helpful to you.