# How to use pixelsearch?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been trying to put together this script that clicks on the pixel with the specified color.
It keeps crashing and clicking unrelated spots.

Is there a better way to implement this? This is what I have (sorry i'm very new to this)

```
Loop {

PixelSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 400, 300, 1800, 800, 821A83, Fast
    if (ErrorLevel){
        MsgBox, no
    }
    else if (!ErrorLevel)
    {
        Click, %OutputVarX%, %OutputVarY% Down
        Sleep 2000
        Click, Up
    }
} Until, limit > 0


limit = 0
 
^w::
limit += 1
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar post a little while ago that might help you [(AHK) Can't seem to get a pixel color statement working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001961/ahk-cant-seem-to-get-a-pixel-color-statement-working). Basically using a Timer instead of a Loop would probably be more helpful to you. I edited your code below to what I *think* might work, but still believe the Timer is a better solution (command SetTimer).

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen ; Or 'Relative' as you desire
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
 ; this tells the the pixel search to be relative to the screen
 ; and the mouse click as well. that might be what is missing here.
Loop {
    PixelSearch, OutputVarX, OutputVarY, 400, 300, 1800, 800, 0x821A83, Fast ; decimal or hexadecimal (including "0x" prefix)
    if (ErrorLevel) {
        MsgBox, no
    }
    else if (!ErrorLevel)
    {
        Click, %OutputVarX%, %OutputVarY%, Down
        Sleep 2000
        Click, Up
    }
} Until (limit > 0)
limit = 0
Return
; each block should have a Return unless you want it
; to drop into the code below


 
^w::
limit += 1
return
```